# mkdir fails although the directory exists and I have seem to have write permissions

Tags: git-bash, mkdir

I'm using GitBash in Windows 10. I would like to create a folder in `/c/Users/User.Name/Documents` (the forward slashes are as they appear in GitBash. In Windows Explorer they would be `C:\Users\User.Name\Documents`).

If I `cd` into `/c/Users/User.Name/Documents` and type `mkdir=test` it fails with `mkdir: cannot create directory 'test': No such file or directory`.

Permissions on the `Documents` folder are `drwxr-xr-x`. I am the folder owner: `whoamI = User.Name` which is also the owner name on the `Documents` folder that I am trying to create a subdirectory in (seen by running `ls -lh while in /c/Users/User.Name`). If I `cd ..` into `/c/Users/User.Name` and `mkdir=test` then the command works. I am the owner of and have the same permissions in `/c/Users/User.Name` and `/c/Users/User.Name/Documents`. The path `/c/Users/User.Name/Documents` is the actual path, I am not trying to access via a symbolic link.

I can create the '`test`' folder manually in `/c/users/User.Name/Documents` using Windows Explorer, in which case I can see it when I `cd` into `Documents`. If I try remove it with `rm -r test` then it fails with `rm: cannot remove 'test': Permission denied`. Permissions on the folder are `drwxr-xr-x`, it is owned by myself.

I'm guessing I don't understand the ownership/permissions correctly. Could anyone advise how to solve this? I found a similar question here, where they suggest changing folder permissions, but to the best of my knowledge I have full permissions and own the folder: [mkdir-doesnt-work-when-im-in-my-documents-but-does-work-when-im-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040504/mkdir-doesnt-work-when-im-in-my-documents-but-does-work-when-im-in-c).

Comment: What are the permissions on `/c/Users/User.Name`?

Comment: If I cd into /c/Users and run ls -lh, /c/Users/User.Name has drwxr-xr-x next to it.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions of `drwxr-xr-x` more or less explain what is going on. Only the owner is allowed to write in that directory, denoted by the `w` in the first grouping of permissions.

To create a directory there you could use `chmod` to alter the permissions. 766 would allow everyone to read and write. There is a good description of Linux permissions [here](https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html).

However, it is likely that any `chmod` command will fail because the gitbash terminal thinks that root is the owner of the documents directory. To prove this out, run `ls -al` in the directory above documents to see the owner. If root is the owner you probably need to add `sudo` before the `mkdir` or `chmod` command. Or you can change the owner which is done with the `chown` command but may have unintended consequences in Windows.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the inputs. When I run ls -al the owner is User.Name (name in the second column of output). If I type whoamI, the output is also User.Name. For this reason I understood my profile to be owner and expected write permissions. I checked the folder permissions via Windows Document Properties and my profile shows up as owner there with full permissions.